# There should be a better way to write the code which will not throw NoMethodError, i am stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There should be a better way to write the code which will not throw NoMethodError, I am stuck.
My stack trace

```
# NoMethodError · undefined method `account' for nil:NilClass

def email_talent_match_only_one(talent, match) 
  @talent = talent 
  @position = match.position 
  @account = match.position.account    

  if @account.present? and @talent.present?
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly common error in Ruby. When you're trying to retrieve the account `match.position` is returning nil. You are then trying to call `account` on `NilClass` which is causing the error.

If this is expected you may want to use the `&.` syntax or the `try` method which will return `nil` rather than throw an error.

```
@account = match.position&.account
# or
@account = match.position.try(:account)
```